# Drop a 5TB collection in Mongo without bringing down the db

Tags: mongodb, replication

In our Mongo configuration we have a replica set with a primary and 2 secondaries. We currently have a collection that is about 5TB in size that we want to drop completely. From reading docs it sounds like just dropping the collection would lock the database. Seems like it might take a bit to delete 5TB and anything more than a few minutes downtime really isn't an option.

I tried deleting records a little bit at a time via query and remove commands, but this still slowed the db down to a crawl.

I've thought about taking the primary out of the set, dropping the collection and then putting it back in the set as primary, but what will the impact be of having those changes replicate to the secondaries? Is it still just going to use a ton of cpu and lock things up?

The end goal is to move all of our mongo instances to smaller disks, so it would be nice if there was an option that allowed us to tackle both the migration and the deletion of the data at the same time.

Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: Are you writing any data in the collection actively or all the writes are stopped for the collection?

Comment: Dropping a collection is not at all the same as removing all documents from the collection. It is a lot faster. Granted, I didn't have to delete 5TB collections, but on a few-GB sized collections it is near-instantaneous. (just tried it on a 40GB collection)

Comment: it's like removing a forest by chopping it down tree by tree vs nuking it from orbit. You can go much faster if you don't need to preserve partial data. For example, it doesn't make sense to update an index on each document removal when you _know_ that in the end there will be no index. Which is to say, dropping the collection should not lock your db even for a minute.

Comment: No, not currently writing any data to the collection. As far as just dropping the collection, the concern is how long the db will be locked for. I know it's more efficient to drop the collection than try to delete records.

Comment: @user2708122: try it and tell us :)

Comment: @SergioTulentsev when you deleted your 40GB collection what was your storage engine? MMAPv1 or WiredTiger? From what I've read they handle collection dropping differently. Sounds like MMAPv1 just drops any references to the collection without actually cleaning up the data, while WiredTiger actually attempts to free the space. I can see the later potentially using up some resources to do the delete.

Comment: @user2708122: WT. It did cause a pause. Noticeable to the human eye, but still sub-second. I'd estimate that to be 300-500ms.